# Panel tab stop working after some clicks on next or previous button

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to understand what is happening with my panel tab inside a modal but I couldn't figure out so far.

In the beggining, the panel tab works perfectly but after a few clicks on the 'next' or 'previous' button, some images are not loaded anymore as expected.

After some tries, the panel goes back and works again. I don't know what is happening.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- modal area start-->
{% for product in products %}
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_box-{{ product.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <div class="modal_body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        {% include 'base_modal_area.html' %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
<!-- modal area end-->
```

And here is the 'base_modal_area.html':

```
{% load static %}

<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
    <div class="modal_tab">
        <div class="tab-content product-details-large">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab1" role="tabpanel" >
                <div class="modal_tab_img">
                    <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="modal_tab_img">
                    <img src="{% static 'img/product/product2-big.jpg' %}" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="modal_tab_img">
                    <img src="{% static 'img/product/product3-big.jpg' %}" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="modal_tab_img">
                    <img src="{% static 'img/product/blank_img.png' %}" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="modal_tab_button">
            <ul class="nav product_navactive owl-carousel" role="tablist">
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-selected="false"><img src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt=""></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                     <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2" aria-selected="false"><img src="{% static 'img/product/product2-big.jpg' %}" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3" role="tab" aria-controls="tab3" aria-selected="false"><img src="{% static 'img/product/product3-big.jpg' %}" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4" role="tab" aria-controls="tab4" aria-selected="false"><img src="{% static 'img/product/blank_img.png' %}" alt=""></a>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12">
    <div class="modal_right">
        <div class="modal_title mb-10">
            <h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal_price mb-10">
            <span class="new_price">R$ {{ product.sell_price }}</span>
            <!--<span class="old_price" >$78.99</span>-->
        </div>
         <div class="see_all">
             <a href="{% url 'root:detail' product.id %}">Ir na página do produto</a>
         </div>
        <div class="modal_add_to_cart mb-15">
            <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}">
                <input min="0" max="100" step="2" value="1" type="number">
                <button type="submit">Adicionar ao Carrinho</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal_description mb-15">
            <p>{{ product.description|linebreaks }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help?

EDIT:
To illustrate the scenario: there are 4 images in this panel.
If I click in the fourth photo, it is showed without any problem. After that, if I click in the 'next' arrow and then in the next image, it is not loaded.

EDIT 2: Added JS code

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    new WOW().init();  

    /*---background image---*/
    function dataBackgroundImage() {
        $('[data-bgimg]').each(function () {
            var bgImgUrl = $(this).data('bgimg');
            $(this).css({
                'background-image': 'url(' + bgImgUrl + ')', // + meaning concat
            });
        });
    }
    
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        dataBackgroundImage();
    });
   
    

    /*---slider activation---*/
    $('.slider_area').owlCarousel({
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true,
        nav: false,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayTimeout: 8000,
        items: 1,
        dots:true,
    });
    
    /*---product_column3 activation---*/
    $('.product_column3').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '0',
        slidesToShow: 5,
        arrows:true,
        rows: 2,
        prevArrow:'<button class="prev_arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>',
        nextArrow:'<button class="next_arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>', 
        responsive:[
            {
              breakpoint: 480,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                  slidesToScroll: 1,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 768,
              settings: {
                  slidesToShow: 2,
                  slidesToScroll: 2,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 992,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                  slidesToScroll: 3,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 1200,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4,
                  slidesToScroll: 4,
              }
            },
        ]
    });
    
    /*---product row activation---*/
    $('.product_row1').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '0',
        slidesToShow: 5,
        arrows:true,
        prevArrow:'<button class="prev_arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>',
        nextArrow:'<button class="next_arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>', 
        responsive:[
            {
              breakpoint: 480,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                  slidesToScroll: 1,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 768,
              settings: {
                  slidesToShow: 2,
                  slidesToScroll: 2,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 992,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                  slidesToScroll: 3,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 1200,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4,
                  slidesToScroll: 4,
              }
            },
           
        ]
    });
    
    /*---product row 2 activation---*/
    $('.product_row2').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '0',
        slidesToShow: 4,
        arrows:true,
        prevArrow:'<button class="prev_arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>',
        nextArrow:'<button class="next_arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>', 
        responsive:[
            {
              breakpoint: 480,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                  slidesToScroll: 1,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 768,
              settings: {
                  slidesToShow: 2,
                  slidesToScroll: 2,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 992,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                  slidesToScroll: 3,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 1200,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                  slidesToScroll: 4,
              }
            },
           
        ]
    });
    
    /*---blog column3 activation---*/
    $('.blog_column3').owlCarousel({
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true,
        nav: true,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayTimeout: 8000,
        items: 3,
        dots:false,
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
                0:{
                items:1,
            },
            768:{
                items:2,
            },
            992:{
                items:3,
            },
          
        }
    });
    
    /*---blog active activation---*/
    $('.blog_thumb_active').owlCarousel({
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true,
        nav: true,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayTimeout: 8000,
        items: 1,
        dots:true,
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
    });
    
    /*---single product activation---*/
    $('.single-product-active').owlCarousel({
        autoplay: false, // was true
        loop: false, // was true
        nav: false, // was true
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayTimeout: 8000,
        items: 4,
        margin:15,
        dots:false,
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
                0:{
                items:1,
            },
            320:{
                items:2,
            },
            992:{
                items:3,
            },
            1200:{
                items:4,
            },


          }
    });
    
    /*---product navactive activation---*/
    $('.product_navactive').owlCarousel({
        autoplay: false, // was true
        loop: false, // was true
        nav: false, // was true
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayTimeout: 8000,
        items: 4,
        dots:false,
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
                0:{
                items:1,
            },
            250:{
                items:2,
            },
            480:{
                items:3,
            },
            768:{
                items:4,
            },
          
        }
    });

    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('.product_navactive').resize();
    })

    $('.product_navactive a').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var $href = $(this).attr('href');

      $('.product_navactive a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      $('.product-details-large .tab-pane').removeClass('active show');
      $('.product-details-large '+ $href ).addClass('active show');

    })
       
    /*---testimonial active activation---*/
    $('.testimonial_active').owlCarousel({
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true,
        nav: false,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayTimeout: 8000,
        items: 1,
        dots:true,
    });
    
    /*--- Magnific Popup---*/
    $('.instagram_pupop').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        }
    });

    /*--- Magnific Popup Video---*/
    $('.video_popup').magnificPopup({
        type: 'iframe',
        removalDelay: 300,
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade'
    });
    
    /*--- Magnific Popup Video---*/
    $('.port_popup').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        }
    });
 
    /*--- niceSelect---*/
     $('.select_option').niceSelect();
    
    /*---  Accordion---*/
    $(".faequently-accordion").collapse({
        accordion:true,
        open: function() {
        this.slideDown(300);
      },
      close: function() {
        this.slideUp(300);
      }     
    });   

    /*--- counterup activation ---*/
    $('.counter_number').counterUp({
        delay: 10,
        time: 1000
    });

    /*---  ScrollUp Active ---*/
    $.scrollUp({
        scrollText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i>',
        easingType: 'linear',
        scrollSpeed: 900,
        animation: 'fade'
    });   
    
    /*---countdown activation---*/
        
     $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
        $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
        $this.html(event.strftime('<div class="countdown_area"><div class="single_countdown"><div class="countdown_number">%D</div><div class="countdown_title">days</div></div><div class="single_countdown"><div class="countdown_number">%H</div><div class="countdown_title">hrs</div></div><div class="single_countdown"><div class="countdown_number">%M</div><div class="countdown_title">mins</div></div><div class="single_countdown"><div class="countdown_number">%S</div><div class="countdown_title">secs</div></div></div>'));     
               
       });
    }); 
    
       /*---MailChimp---*/
    $('#mc-form').ajaxChimp({
        language: 'en',
        callback: mailChimpResponse,
        // ADD YOUR MAILCHIMP URL BELOW HERE!
        url: 'http://devitems.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=6bbb9b6f5827bd842d9640c82&amp;id=05d85f18ef'

    });
    function mailChimpResponse(resp) {

        if (resp.result === 'success') {
            $('.mailchimp-success').addClass('active')
            $('.mailchimp-success').html('' + resp.msg).fadeIn(900);
            $('.mailchimp-error').fadeOut(400);

        } else if(resp.result === 'error') {
            $('.mailchimp-error').html('' + resp.msg).fadeIn(900);
        }  
    }
    
    
    
    /*---slider-range here---*/
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 0, 500 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
       }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
       " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    
    /*niceSelect*/
     $('.niceselect_option').niceSelect();
    
    /*---elevateZoom---*/
    $("#zoom1").elevateZoom({
        gallery:'gallery_01', 
        responsive : true,
        cursor: 'crosshair',
        zoomType : 'inner'
    
    });  
    
    /*---portfolio Isotope activation---*/
      $('.portfolio_gallery').imagesLoaded( function() {

        var $grid = $('.portfolio_gallery').isotope({
           itemSelector: '.gird_item',
            percentPosition: true,
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: '.gird_item'
            }
        });

          /*---ilter items on button click---*/
        $('.portfolio_button').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
           var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
           $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
            
           $(this).siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');
        });
       
    });
    
    /*---tooltip---*/
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    


   

       
    /*---Newsletter Popup---*/
   
        setTimeout(function() {
            if($.cookie('shownewsletter')==1) $('.newletter-popup').hide();
            $('#subscribe_pemail').keypress(function(e) {
                if(e.which == 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    email_subscribepopup();
                }
                var name= $(this).val();
                  $('#subscribe_pname').val(name);
            });
            $('#subscribe_pemail').change(function() {
             var name= $(this).val();
                      $('#subscribe_pname').val(name);
            });
            //transition effect
            if($.cookie("shownewsletter") != 1){
                $('.newletter-popup').bPopup();
            }
            $('#newsletter_popup_dont_show_again').on('change', function(){
                if($.cookie("shownewsletter") != 1){   
                    $.cookie("shownewsletter",'1')
                }else{
                    $.cookie("shownewsletter",'0')
                }
            }); 
        }, 2500);

    

 
    
    /*---mini cart activation---*/
    $('.cart_link > a').on('click', function(){
        $('.mini_cart,.off_canvars_overlay').addClass('active')
    });
    
    $('.mini_cart_close > a,.off_canvars_overlay').on('click', function(){
        $('.mini_cart,.off_canvars_overlay').removeClass('active')
    });
    
    
    
     /*---canvas menu activation---*/
    $('.canvas_open').on('click', function(){
        $('.Offcanvas_menu_wrapper,.off_canvars_overlay').addClass('active')
    });
    
    $('.canvas_close,.off_canvars_overlay').on('click', function(){
        $('.Offcanvas_menu_wrapper,.off_canvars_overlay').removeClass('active')
    });
    
    
    /*---Off Canvas Menu---*/
    var $offcanvasNav = $('.offcanvas_main_menu'),
        $offcanvasNavSubMenu = $offcanvasNav.find('.sub-menu');
    $offcanvasNavSubMenu.parent().prepend('<span class="menu-expand"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>');
    
    $offcanvasNavSubMenu.slideUp();
    
    $offcanvasNav.on('click', 'li a, li .menu-expand', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ( ($this.parent().attr('class').match(/\b(menu-item-has-children|has-children|has-sub-menu)\b/)) && ($this.attr('href') === '#' || $this.hasClass('menu-expand')) ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($this.siblings('ul:visible').length){
                $this.siblings('ul').slideUp('slow');
            }else {
                $this.closest('li').siblings('li').find('ul:visible').slideUp('slow');
                $this.siblings('ul').slideDown('slow');
            }
        }
        if( $this.is('a') || $this.is('span') || $this.attr('clas').match(/\b(menu-expand)\b/) ){
            $this.parent().toggleClass('menu-open');
        }else if( $this.is('li') && $this.attr('class').match(/\b('menu-item-has-children')\b/) ){
            $this.toggleClass('menu-open');
        }
    });
    
    
    /*js ripples activation*/
    $('.js-ripples').ripples({
        resolution: 512,
        dropRadius: 20,
        perturbance: 0.04
    });

 
    
    
    
})(jQuery); 
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    new WOW().init();  

    
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        dataBackgroundImage();
    });
    
    /*---stickey menu---*/
    $(window).on('scroll',function() {    
           var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
           if (scroll < 100) {
            $(".sticky-header").removeClass("sticky");
           }else{
            $(".sticky-header").addClass("sticky");
           }
    });
    

    /*---slider activation---*/
    $('.slider_area').owlCarousel({
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true,
        nav: false,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayTimeout: 8000,
        items: 1,
        dots:true,
    });
    
    /*---product_column3 activation---*/
    $('.product_column3').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '0',
        slidesToShow: 5,
        arrows:true,
        rows: 2,
        prevArrow:'<button class="prev_arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>',
        nextArrow:'<button class="next_arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>', 
        responsive:[
            {
              breakpoint: 480,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                  slidesToScroll: 1,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 768,
              settings: {
                  slidesToShow: 2,
                  slidesToScroll: 2,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 992,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                  slidesToScroll: 3,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 1200,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4,
                  slidesToScroll: 4,
              }
            },
        ]
    });
    
    /*---product row activation---*/
    $('.product_row1').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '0',
        slidesToShow: 5,
        arrows:true,
        prevArrow:'<button class="prev_arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>',
        nextArrow:'<button class="next_arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>', 
        responsive:[
            {
              breakpoint: 480,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                  slidesToScroll: 1,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 768,
              settings: {
                  slidesToShow: 2,
                  slidesToScroll: 2,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 992,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                  slidesToScroll: 3,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 1200,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4,
                  slidesToScroll: 4,
              }
            },
           
        ]
    });
    
    /*---product row 2 activation---*/
    $('.product_row2').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '0',
        slidesToShow: 4,
        arrows:true,
        prevArrow:'<button class="prev_arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>',
        nextArrow:'<button class="next_arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>', 
        responsive:[
            {
              breakpoint: 480,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                  slidesToScroll: 1,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 768,
              settings: {
                  slidesToShow: 2,
                  slidesToScroll: 2,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 992,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                  slidesToScroll: 3,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 1200,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                  slidesToScroll: 4,
              }
            },
           
        ]
    });
   
    
    
    /*---single product activation---*/
    $('.single-product-active').owlCarousel({
        autoplay: false, // was true
        loop: false, // was true
        nav: false, // was true
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayTimeout: 8000,
        items: 4,
        margin:15,
        dots:false,
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
                0:{
                items:1,
            },
            320:{
                items:2,
            },
            992:{
                items:3,
            },
            1200:{
                items:4,
            },


          }
    });
    
    /*---product navactive activation---*/
    $('.product_navactive').owlCarousel({
        autoplay: false, // was true
        loop: false, // was true
        nav: false, // was true
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayTimeout: 8000,
        items: 4,
        dots:false,
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
                0:{
                items:1,
            },
            250:{
                items:2,
            },
            480:{
                items:3,
            },
            768:{
                items:4,
            },
          
        }
    });

    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('.product_navactive').resize();
    })

    $('.product_navactive a').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var $href = $(this).attr('href');

      $('.product_navactive a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      $('.product-details-large .tab-pane').removeClass('active show');
      $('.product-details-large '+ $href ).addClass('active show');

    })
```

Comment: I'll assume you handle your click next in a javascript function that you didn't add in your question. I assume that when the user clicks on next you iterate the index of the visible item by 1. What you need to do is add a constraint there, when the index is greater than your items length minus 1 it should be reset to 0. If you add your js code I could provide a more accurate answer.

Comment: @StavrosAngelis, added the JS code.

Comment: If I understand your code correctly I think the problem is that you are loading an owlcarousel inside the modal. This throws off the calculations of owl carousel regarding the width of the panel. Unfortunately without a code sandbox it's really difficult to identify the exact problem.